# Wordpress REST API over SSL (https) is giving me a 404

Tags: wordpress, apache, ssl

So I am using my Wordpress as my backend to store custom post types.

It's hosted on an google cloud click-to-deploy Wordpress instance running Apache HTTP Server (2.4.10) and Debian 8. I configured an SSL certificate using letsencrypt following this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-debian-8.

My endpoints work over http, but not over https. When I try to fetch using https, I get a 404 error. The requested URL /wp-json/wp/v2/editorial was not found on this server, at the bottom it says Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server at www.....com Port 443

Any help please let me know. I've been stuck on this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem yesterday.

Letsencrypt creates an additional .conf file for port 443 (ssl).

Wordpress requires the following in both the Port 80 .conf file and the port 443 file.  (change /var/www/wordpress to your working directory path.)

```
    <Directory "/var/www/wordpress">
        Require all granted
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride FileInfo
        FallbackResource /index.php
    </Directory>
```

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/apache-web-server-configuration-file-for-wordpress/